# Expected delay for youtube feeds?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

We switched over to YouTube from a previously developed internal video system, and right now I've got it going on public upload feeds for users. The problem comes when we first got only about a dozen out of 150 or so videos available from the primary user's account. Over time of the day that number rose to about 50, and its stayed there. I found one post on the YouTube API forums about delay, but no word on how long I can expect that.

Anyone have experience about this to tell me what to expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expected latencies can vary, and are documented here (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html) - ways you can minimize it:

1) Upload the video as public. If you upload the video as private first, this will leave the video out of the fast-track indexing

2) Make an authenticated request to the user feed, this will guarantee the freshest data that the API has.
ie. http://gdata.youtube.com/api/feeds/users/username/uploads (with a dev key and auth token for 'username') instead of http://gdata.youtube.com/api/feeds/videos?author=username

Comment: This answers my question, but it had turned out that I asked the wrong question in the first place. If you think are getting a delay and items aren't showing up, be sure you are getting more than the first "page" of results. I was using django-syncr and it completely ignores any more than 25 videos, which certainly surprised me (And I patched it)

Comment: ah :) Glad you figured it out.