# YouTube API v3 response is missing videos

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Why is the response for this upload playlists - UUbLd_GVzZaFSb7ZqY0iz2TA - is missing the 2 latest video uploads (both uploaded 8 months ago)?
It doesn't happen with the other upload playlists I've checked.

The query using Google's API explorer:

http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=id%252C+snippet%252C+contentDetails&maxResults=3&playlistId=UUbLd_GVzZaFSb7ZqY0iz2TA&_h=6&

The upload playlist for that channel:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUbLd_GVzZaFSb7ZqY0iz2TA

Comment: Did you ever get resolution on this? I'm experiencing something similar, and can't seem to find much information on this particular issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

"Standard feeds are updated periodically, with the update frequency varying from feed to feed. Many feeds are updated every 30 to 40 minutes but other feeds – such as those that capture daily, weekly or monthly results – may only be updated hourly or even daily."

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1

Also see this earlier post: [Expected delay for youtube feeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923513/expected-delay-for-youtube-feeds)

Comment: Thanks, but I know that. The reason I asked is that the latest video uploaded 8 months ago, giving it plenty of time to update everywhere.